# How to add inputs inside the dropdown in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to add input inside the button dropdown but it overlaps the dropdown's space. Please see my code below.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="dropdown-header">
       <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                 <div class="form-group">
                       <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control">
                       <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Ok</button>
                  </div>
             </div>
        </div>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Post your problem as working solution in JsFilddle or other play ground.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I just changed my code to this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" min="0">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">OK</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```